# What is the simplest way to show a pop up in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of items in my web app.  Currently these have a name and a single link:

- Item 1 NEW
- Item 2 NEW

The user has requested further functionality from this list, so now I need to show a name, a date, a description, then three links

- Item 1 11/11/10 blurb NEW EDIT APPEND
- Item 2 03/02/10 blurb NEW EDIT APPEND

Unfortunately, screen estate is tight, and I can't fit all this into the allocated space.

I'd like to display "Item 1 11/11/10 blurb" as a link, which when clicked on, pops up a window asking what the user would like to do next.

I'm a total newbie at Javascript, on a tight timescale, and am not sure where to start with this.

We need to be compatible with IE6 (groan)

What should I use?  Can someone point me to any useful resources or example??

We're using ASP.NET MVC3...

Cheers!

Comment: I think it whould be better to use some `Modal window` instead of popup. there are plenty jquery plugins for that.

Comment: Does it have to be a pop-up? Can you link another page/view instead?

Comment: Yes, I could link the new view - would probably be easier!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use jquery I would recommend using the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  It's easy to use and setup. Take a look at the link for a demo.